# How do I assign the values returned in a list of lists from an invocable action in Apex?

Tags: salesforce, apex, salesforce-lightning

I want to have a record-triggered flow that calls an Apex method and uses the return value to update the record. I've created the Apex code, which looks like this:

```
public class TestTest {
    
    @InvocableMethod(label='ExampleMethod' description='Returns the input string. Just an example for testing purposes.')
    public static List<List<ReturnVariables>> exampleMethod(List<InputVariables> inputVars) {
        
        List<List<ReturnVariables>> returnVarsList = new List<List<ReturnVariables>>();
        List<ReturnVariables> returnVars = new List<ReturnVariables>();
        
        for (InputVariables inputVar : inputVars){
            ReturnVariables returnVar = new returnVariables();
            returnVar.returnString = inputVar.inputString;
            returnVars.add(returnVar);
        }
        returnVarsList.add(returnVars);
        return returnVarsList;
    }
    
    public class InputVariables {
        @InvocableVariable
        public String inputString;
        
        public InputVariables() {
            
        }
    }
    
    public class ReturnVariables {
        @InvocableVariable
        public String returnString;
        
        public ReturnVariables() {
            
        }
    }
    
}
```

I originally had the method return List<ReturnVariables>, which worked fine for a single record, but whenever Salesforce bulkified it for multiple records I got the error message "The number of results does not match the number of interviews that were executed in a single bulk execution request." Because of this, I changed the return type to List<List<ReturnVariables>> as suggested by other posts on Stack Overflow.

Unfortunately, now that I have done this, I cannot find a way to get the returned string in the flow to update the record because it is now returning a list. I can't even seem to assign the returned value to a list variable. I need to get the output string somehow but I can't figure out how.

If anyone could help me with this, that would be appreciated.